# Responsive icon menu submenu

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I want to design icon menu & click to expand submenu using HTML CSS.
[I want to design this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4aaeg.png)

I want show the sub menu next row of the responsive div as shows above image. but the problem is the sub menu appear next line but rest of the parent menu goes under it see the problem from the bellow image
[this is the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tbkW7.png)
I used bootstrap4 and following html

```
<div class="icon-bar" id="myGroup">
    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="index.html" data-toggle="collapse" role="button" aria-expanded="false">
        <i class="menu-icon mdi mdi-television fa-4x"></i>
        <br>
        <span class="menu-title">Dashboard</span>
    </a>

    <a class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" href="#Authentication" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample1">
        <i class="menu-icon fa fa-handshake-o fa-4x"></i>
        <br>
        <span class="menu-title">Authentication</span>
    </a>

    <div class="collapse" id="Authentication" data-parent="#myGroup">
        <div class="card card-body">

            <a class="btn btn-primary btnsubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample1" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample1">
                <i class="fa fa-angle-right fa-4x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                <br>
                <span class="menu-title">Groups</span>
            </a>

            <a class="btn btn-primary btnsubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample1" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample1">
                <i class="fa fa-angle-right fa-4x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                <br>
                <span class="menu-title">Users</span>
            </a>
        </div>
     </div>

     <a class="btn btn-primary" href="pages/entity-profile-list.html" role="button" data-toggle="collapse"  aria-expanded="false" >
         <i class="menu-icon mdi mdi-television fa-4x"></i>
         <span class="menu-title">Entity Profile</span>
     </a>

     <a class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" href="#objectProfile" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="objectProfile">
         <i class="menu-icon fa fa-object-group fa-4x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
         <br>
         <span class="menu-title">Object Profiles</span>
     </a> .......
```

Can anyone please help me? [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ripon23/6hxt9v7s/)

Comment: did you try flex?

Comment: yes but no luck

Comment: Could you ad a JSFiddle or something like that with both HTML and CSS?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ripon23/6hxt9v7s/

Answer (score 1):

this is actually quick and dirty and will not work 100%, but it could give you hint into the right direction. The intention here is to move the anchor elements, or better move the "opening menu" to the right position.

```
function test(element){
    var element = $(element),
        elemWidth = element.outerWidth(),
        rightSpace = ($('#myGroup').width() - (element.offset().left + element .outerWidth())),
        idx = parseFloat(rightSpace / elemWidth).toFixed(0),
        moveelem = $(element).nextAll().slice(1,idx);

    var objectProfile = $('#objectProfile');

        element.after(moveelem);

    objectProfile.after()

}


$('#myGroup > .btn.btn-primary').on('click', function(el){
    test($(this));
})
```

[here is your enhanced fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mattopen/24npdLky/)

Comment: it did not do the same thing when I click on the same icon couple of times

Comment: @TanjinaAnwer as mentioned, it is not yet fully developed and need a little bit enhancement from your side. But it should show you, how to deal with this. Actually i do not have much time to develope it all for you.